# Android - Gradle Error

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

For some reason I keep getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':facebook:processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merging failed. See console for more info.
```

Here are my build.gradle files and Manifest files:

App

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.3.1.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.yyy.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:name=".delegates.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.app.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.LegalActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.CreateUserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainTabActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ChangeEmailActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ChangePasswordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.ShowCardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.PunchCardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.AddCardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.Scanner"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Facebook

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile files('libs/bolts.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.facebook.android">
    <application/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

The really weird thing is that it works on my laptop but not on my desktop. I've re-imported the app, and re-synced it but no idea why its not letting my build it.

Comment: Make sure your SDKs are up to date in your ADTs SDK Manager. I'm almost certain it's a versioning issue with your SDKs.

Comment: I recently updated all of the SDKs using the Android SDK Manager

Comment: did you clean and rebuild?

Comment: Ya I did, still the same error.

Comment: What is the error in console? Gradle has introduced a new manifest merger. It might be something related to that

Comment: What version of Android Studio and gradle are you using?

Comment: @SaneeshCS the error in the console is Error:(3) Failed to parse <uses-sdk minSdkVersion='L'>: must be an integer number or codename.
Error:(3) Failed to parse <uses-sdk targetSdkVersion='L'>: must be an integer number or codename. But these files are generated when you build the project.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Im using android studio 0.5.4 and this gradle: com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.3.1.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
```

To

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
```

And make sure u have updated build tools in the sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest Android Studio(0.8.X) and new Gradle Plugin(0.12.+).

Change buildToolsVersion in build.gradle to 19.1.0 or later.

Comment: this doesn't do anything. still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion weren't matching and it was set to a version of the buildTools which wasn't installed.